# is "I know the things I saw" common?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

> [what](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/what?q=what): the thing or things that; whatever
>
> Ex: I know what I saw

Most people say "*I know what I saw*" and not many say "*I know the things I saw*"

is "*I know the things I saw*" idiomatic or common?

Comment: As you defined it, "what" can refer to one thing or to several things. Its dual singular-plural meaning makes it more popular than "the thing (that)" or "the things (that)," which, being specific as to the number, are more restricted in use: you only saw one thing or more than one thing. "what" covers both cases. Also, "what" is better than "the thing(s)" from a stylistic point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the things (that) I saw.

I know what l saw.

Both sentences are grammatical and have the same meaning, but the use of the pronoun "what" instead of the phrase "the thing(s) that"  is far more idiomatic or common.